# Saving Blender file in the same directory as original file and changing the name

Tags: python

My blender file is saved in a specific directory when I start the project. This location can be anywhere on the computer, so the directory can change.

Example. C:/Documents/MyFile.blend.

My objective is to use a script to automatically save my work in the same directory, as the original.

So, C:/Documents/StepOne.blend.
In the end I want to use this script many different times at strategic points in my workflow.
So, I will end up with.

```
C:/Documents/MyFile.blend
C:/Documents/StepOne.blend
C:/Documents/StepTwo.blend
```

etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some sample code that does what you want.  You'll have to adapt it to your purpose:

```py
import bpy
import pathlib

blender_file_path = pathlib.Path(bpy.data.filepath)
if bpy.data.filepath == '':
    print('You are working from an unsaved Blend file.  Do you really want to do that?')
else:
    print(f'You are working from file "{blender_file_path.name}"'
        + f' in directory (folder) {blender_file_path.parent}')
        
new_file_path = blender_file_path.parent / "newfilename.blend"
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=str(new_file_path))
```

The `if` statement is meant to demonstrate the difference between working in an unsaved and a saved blend file.  In the unsaved case there is no path.  After the print statement in the then clause you'll need to deal with this, perhaps by setting the filepath to a default path name.

[`save_as_mainfile`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html) saves the current file to the new file name.

You can simplify this code depending on what your purpose is.

[Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is a standard Python library introduced in Python 3.4. It is recommended practice in Blender to use it for manipulating file naem instead of `os` if you don't need features that `os` provides but `pathlib` does not.

Comment: Marty, can we stop the duplicate version from saving? Now it saves StepOn.blend and  StepOne.blend1. The rest of the script is perfect.

Comment: @MichaelTeiniker the backup save feature is a property you can deactivate in the preferences. You can also delete the file afterwards with `os.remove(filepath)` note you can also change directly a file name with `Path(bpy.data.filepath).with_stem("newfilename")` instead of `Path(bpy.data.filepath).parent / "newfilename.blend"`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_stem